# Много file_get_contents() вызывают ошибку 500

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Я пишу бота для телеграмма на php.

У меня есть база данных, из нее я получаю ID канала, в одной функции смотрю описание канала с помощью file_get_contents(), во второй задаю новое описание с помощью file_get_contents(). каналов более тысячи и сервер не выдерживает не до конца выполняет скрипт, как можно оптимизировать? С многопоточностью в php еще не знаком.

То есть с каждым каналом оно делает 2 запроса, каналов 1700, итого 3400 запросов, php не успевает обработать и сервер умирает, выдает 500 Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. успев при этом у некоторых поменять описание

куски кода:

```
$query = "SELECT `ID_Channel_tg`, `TIMEZONE` FROM `u747826294_mtm`.`CLOCKOBOT_Channel` ORDER By `ID_Channel` LIMIT 25 OFFSET ".$_GET['n'];
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if($result){
    while($value = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        getChat($value["ID_Channel_tg"],$value["TIMEZONE"]);
    }
}

================================================================
function getChat($chatId,$timezone){
    $data = file_get_contents($GLOBALS[website]."/getChat?chat_id=".$chatId);
    ...операции с описанием...
    setChatDescription($chatId, $string);
}
function setChatDescription($chatId, $reply){
    $url = $GLOBALS[website]."/setChatDescription?chat_id=".$chatId."&description=".$reply;
}
```

Comment: обычно когда сервер не успевает обработать запрос, он падает HTTP 504, а не HTTP 500. А что пишется в лог сервера? Многопоточность тут слабо поможет, т.к. у tg довольно относительно жёсткие ограничения количество запросов в минуту. Ну и +1 к использованию rabbitmq

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть несколько путей решения, вот некоторые из них:
1) Разбить выполнение на "пачки" (на английском batch processing), т.е. допустим ваш скрипт находится по адресу `https://example.com/tg_chat.php`, и вы разбиваете обработку ваших каналов на несколько "пачек" и скрипт вызываете следующим образом `https://example.com/tg_chat.php?batchId=1`, `https://example.com/tg_chat.php?batchId=2`, `https://example.com/tg_chat.php?batchId=N`, а свой первоначальный SQL запрос разбиваете части с помощью `LIMIT x OFSSET x`

2) Использовать систему очередей, но я думаю вы сейчас не сможете ее корректно реализовать и использовать. Но если интересно поищите в интернете: `php очереди сообщений`, `php rabbitmq OR kaffka OR gearman`

3) Выполнять эти операции не из браузера, а на сервере через командную консоль или планировщик cron по расписанию.

PS: но для начала советую в начало скрипта поставить вывод всех ошибок, что бы точно определить ошибку и устранить ее, для этого просто вставьте в начале файла после `<?php`

```php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```